# Is there an apt-get package for Sphinx search?

Tags: package-management

I would like to know if there is a package for [Sphinx search](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) hiding out there somewhere. Their download page shows various RPM's, but I was not able to find anything for Ubuntu.

The [install from source](http://www.hackido.com/2009/01/install-sphinx-search-on-ubuntu.html) is super easy, but it would be nice to have it under package management.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install sphinxsearch`

[Ubuntu Packages: Sphinx Search (Lucid)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/sphinxsearch)

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that?

Comment: And for future reference "apt-cache search xxxxx" will help you find packages.  It helps to know the package name and/or use grep to narrow the results.  In this case you could do this:

apt-cache search sphinx | grep search

And you'll see that the package is indeed called sphinxsearch (obviously a trivial example)

Comment: I tend to keep people away from the `apt-cache search` though you are right. There is a web interface for all the packages across all  supported releases of Ubuntu (see my link)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `checkinstall` when installing from source; it will create a .deb file and install the generated package.

There are more details [on the wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall), but, briefly, instead of:

```
sudo make install
```

do:

```
sudo checkinstall
```

and Sphinx will be under package management.

Note that the generated package is really only good for the machine you created it on as it's only for one architecture and lacks most of the important metadata needed for distribution (like prerequisites). However it will allow you to upgrade or uninstall cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

You can add **latest stable** build releases for **2.2.*** of sphinx search to your system.

```
$ add-apt-repository ppa:builds/sphinxsearch-rel22
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install sphinxsearch
```

more info about repository: https://launchpad.net/~builds/+archive/ubuntu/sphinxsearch-rel22/

**PS:** Sorry for responding to old question, but ubuntu still thinks the ,,best'' version is 2.0.4 and i needed 2.2.7 (latest) and after some research i found this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The apt-get install sphinxsearch gives you version 0.9.8, at the download site from Sphinx itself it's at 2.0.8... You might want to not use the apt-get version if you want up-to-date search capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

From the sphinx [documentation](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.2.4.html#quick-tour)

Installing Sphinx packages on Debian and Ubuntu

There are two ways of getting Sphinx for Ubuntu: regular deb packages and the Launchpad PPA repository.

Deb packages:

Sphinx requires a few libraries to be installed on Debian/Ubuntu. Use apt-get to download and install these dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-client unixodbc libpq5
```

Now you can install Sphinx:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i sphinxsearch_2.2.1-beta-0ubuntu11~precise_amd64.deb
```

PPA repository (Ubuntu only).

Installing Sphinx is much easier from Sphinxsearch PPA repository, because you will get all dependencies and can also update Sphinx to the latest version with the same command.

First, add Sphinxsearch repository and update the list of packages:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:builds/sphinxsearch-daily
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Install/update sphinxsearch package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sphinxsearch
```

Sphinx searched daemon can be started/stopped using service command:

```
$ sudo service sphinxsearch start
```

2.4. Installing Sphinx packages on RedHat and CentOS

Currently we distribute Sphinx RPMS and SRPMS on our website for both 5.x and 6.x versions of Red Hat Enterprise Linux, but they can be installed on CentOS as well.

Before installation make sure you have these packages installed:

```
$ yum install postgresql-libs unixODBC
```

Download RedHat RPM from Sphinx website and install it:

```
$ rpm -Uhv sphinx-2.2.1-1.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
```

After preparing configuration file (see Quick tour), you can start searchd daemon:

```
$ service searchd start
```